# TV series in the 90s where people get superpower by sniffing flowers

Tags: story-identification, tv

I couldn't remember anything more than what stated in the title. There are several kinds of flowers, each one gives people a different kind of skill: strength, intelligence etc. It's not really superpower, but exceed the ability of the best human. If I remember correctly, this was not about superhero with cap and mask etc, just about the flowers that give people special ability.

---

### Update

Thanks @Jenayah, I watched it in 1990 or earlier. It was a TV series for kids (I was a kid when I watched it). I'm 90% sure it was from Eastern Europe, but it might also be made in Soviet Union. At the beginning the protagonist had brought back one or two flowers from somewhere, but then more people went there and brought back more kinds of flowers. He had a rival, who were a really annoying boy, but his father was the true antagonist. I can only remember two scenes:

- The annoying boy, who was often lazy and dump, sniffed a flower, and became super smart.
- His father sniffed a flower, and flipped like a gymnast.
- His mother was also bad, but I didn't remember what she did.

The ability given by the flower only lasted for a period of time.

---

### Update 2

This is an [unrelated TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spadla_z_oblakov), but I believe I also watched around the same time (same year or not too far). The themes were also similar, some kids with fancy stuffs. I guess they were imported from the same country.

Comment: Surely you can remember a bit more :) please take a look at [these guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), maybe they'll trigger something. At the very least - where did you watch that, and what language was it in? Was it a translation?

Comment: @Jenayah Thanks, I updated it.

Comment: I remember watching this show in the 80s, unfortunately i do not remember its name but i can add a few more scenes if that helps. The seeds from the flowers came from a meteoric rock that normally was quite small, but sometimes could grow man sized and then act as a portal to a greenhouse with the plants. The annoying boy used his super intelligence to try to invent things that would enhance humans without the flower. One thing he made was a listening device that someone took and used to cheat at a school exam.

Comment: Two other scenes that i remember are one where the annoying boy tried to improve a formula that would enhance peoples senses to be comparable to a dogs, but it also made people bark. The other scene was about a barber that i think was the father of one of the heroes. He pretended to have found a miracle cure for baldness that he sold to his customers, but in reality they were unaware that  he just tricked them to smell a flower that could heal all ills, including baldness.

Comment: @BjornEriksson Thanks, now I also remember the scene that he tricked customers to smell flowers.

Comment: @BjornEriksson About the barber, I believe my answer check out there too, I remember that part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are talking about Létající Čestmír (Flying Cestmir), short TV series made in 1983 in Czechoslovakia.

In this, main character Cestmir enters a meteorite and brings out seeds for the flowers.
When smelled, they had different effects. Giving ability to fly, making them older/younger...

And yes, there was a pretty rotten family that stole some of the flowers, I can quarantee the son got smarter and created a serum that made one's smell better, but in turn also gave the user facial "fur" (see 2nd picture)

[Czech description](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9taj%C3%ADc%C3%AD_%C4%8Cestm%C3%ADr)

[image: Letajici Cestmir]

[image: Facial fur]

Comment: This is definitely the one i remember,.

Comment: @BjornEriksson Glad I was able to help :)